# Problem with anonymouse delegate within foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, delegates

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Collection<Test> tests = new Collection<Test>();
        tests.Add(new Test("test1"));
        tests.Add(new Test("test2"));
        foreach (Test test in tests)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = test.name;
            button.Click+=new EventHandler((object obj, EventArgs arg)=>{
                this.CreateTest(test);
            });
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
    public void CreateTest(Test test)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(test.name);
    }
}
```

when i click the button witch text is 'test1', the messagebox will show 'test2',but my expect is 'test1'.
So ,would anyone please tell me why or what`s wrong with my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup - you're closing over the loop variable. The `test` within the lambda expression refers to the same variable in all your delegates, which means it will end up with the final value at the end of the loop. Take a copy of the value and use that. You're also using a pretty longwinded form of the lambda expression. Here's the fixed and shortened code:

```
foreach (Test test in tests)
{
    // Take a copy of the "test" variable so that each iteration
    // creates a delegate capturing a different variable (and hence a
    // different value)
    Test copy = test;
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = test.name;
    button.Click += (obj, arg) => CreateTest(copy);
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

See [Eric Lippert's blog post on this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more information.